# Отправка JSON запроса в фоне с определенной периодичностью

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service

Приложение делает JSON запрос с помощью DownloadJSONTask, который наследуется от AsyncTask.

```
private class DownloadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,
            Void,
            String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                return result.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //обработка ответа и изменение UI
}
```

Нужно, чтобы эти действия выполнялись в фоне с периодичностью в 1 сутки, UI изменять не нужно, но нужно отправлять уведомление при определенных условиях. Читал про службы но не понял, стоит ли мне их использовать или есть другие способы. Можно ли как-то выполнять AsyncTask из служб или другим образом с определенной пeриодичностью?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте WorkManager . Это самое правильное решение. https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/562-urok-29-workmanager-vvedenie.html